# in js on page refresh its takes me to primary page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

With AJAX, as all functions are loaded on a dynamic page without the page being reloaded or more importantly a URL being changed (except for a hash symbol maybe), clicking the back or refresh button would take you to an entirely different web page or to the beginning of what your dynamic web page was processing basically, I want it should remain on the same page
on index page main div `#content` is placed.

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
var trigger = $('#nav ul li a'),
container = $('#content');
trigger.on('click', function(){
 var $this = $(this)
 target = $this.data('target');
 container.load(target + '.php');
 return false;  
});
});

</script>
```

```css
<style>
#nav ul{
overflow:hidden;
margin: 0;
padding:0;
list-style-type: none;
}
#nav ul li{
float:left;
}
#nav ul li a{
display:inline-block;
padding:18px 15px;
}
#content{
padding:15px;
}
</style>
```

```html
<nav id="nav">
<ul>
 <li><a href="#" data-target="home">home</a></li>
 <li><a href="#" data-target="about">about</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ajax Content is persistent till the point you refresh the page, if you want to retain the values:
You can do that once you send ajax request to page to be rendered store this date in session once you refresh the page you can render this partial from session if it was set before.

User following content for save your page data which you have retrieve during ajax load.

```
session_start();
$page_data = 'set value in this variable during your ajax call';
//save data in $_SESSION
$_SESSION['page_data'] = $page_data;
```

below code use for render data on html:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['page_data']))
    {  $html = $_SESSION['page_data'];}
```

Comment: i stored page id in session but what condition should i put ? how do i work with this         
if(isset($_SESSION['page_data']))
    {  $html = $_SESSION['page_data'];}